# How was Stack Overflow's gameplay designed?

Tags: discussion, gamification

Is there a resource somewhere with a history of Stack Overflow's gameplay changes?

Is there some kind of backlog? It would be interesting to see how it evolved as more and more sites are taking this approach.

Comment: Meta is the right place. You may not find an answer, unless someone writes up an original one, but.

Comment: Gameplay? Stack Overflow is serious business.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Gameplay is jargon for the set of rules that are used to encourage certain behaviour patterns from users.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Also, I just remembered who LittleBobbyTables is. Nice link to XKCD :)

Comment: Not specific to 'gameplay', but the list of [recent feature changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) goes back to 2009....

Answer (score -5):

> Is there a resource somewhere with a history of SO's gameplay changes? Is there some kind of backlog? It would be interesting to see how it evolved as more and more sites are taking this approach.

I've been writing about the gameplay for quite some time. Little is known because most is classified but it is safe to say that -- some how -- early on it was decided that Jeffery Atwood would be king. He pretty much runs this show.

Gameplay here is a lot of like Dungeons and Dragons meets Yahoo Answers. We have "moderators" which are essentially appointed by JA who is kind of like the Dungeon Master. Jeff's moderators, also known as "minions," introduce randomness to this game because Jeff could only hire Microsoft programmers, and MS Windows doesn't have `/dev/rand`. Jeff runs the media here, controls the chat, and even has a little propaganda team that help him with the podcasts (that's gameplay for "radio").

How has gameplay changed? It's slowly become more autocratic. First they introduced bans, then they extended the duration of bans, then they implemented special bans (no one understands how they work). Now we know that you can collect "tags" and "experience." Today there are a few different levels, but the highest acknowledged level comes somewhere around 10k. After you hit 100k EXP, you get a "job offer" which includes hunting rabbits for food... in real life.

I'm not quite sure how to beat this bastard creation. I got banned for two years, and then I [got asked to *"hang out"*](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/314235739758030848) which is bourgeoisie  for [engaging in terrorist activities.](http://www.reddit.com/r/nongolfers).

Comment: Oh man, we should really create a "Who said it?" game one of these days. This one was too obvious. :)

Comment: *Dungeons and Dragons meets Yahoo Answers*. Priceless.

Comment: You have never tried to hack your way out of the ban? I saw some 2d spaceship gamers doing a better job at hacking than you, I am disappointed. I am generally disappointed at the lack of hacking attempts on the SO site. I don't blame SO of course, since this site is dedicated to (answering questions of) newbs. But why there are so few pissed off 1337 hackers is beyond my comprehension. Surely some skilled people visit this site once in a while? P.S. check my apps out sometimes. Love always, telkitty.

Comment: "pissed off 1337 hackers", dude this game doesn't even have armor. If I can't get a blessed breastplate out of the deal, what the hell is the point? The closest thing the game ever had to armor was hats, and they only lasted like a week.

Comment: Still trying to get answer banned I see?

Comment: Was it decided he would be king when he, you know, made the site? Or did he take power in an unlawful coup?

Comment: @EvanCarroll How is the 30-sided dice simulated ;) ?

Comment: @JamesPoulson ask the question on MSO, I'll be glad to answer. This is not the place though.

Comment: Sometimes, the only winning move is not to play.